# mnesia doesn't restart with supervisor

Tags: erlang, erlang-supervisor

I have a problem working with gen_server, supervisor and mnesia. I have supervisor:http://pastebin.com/8rkfrq7D
which fires server module which is starting mnesia. My problem is that when i write

```
erl
c(superv).
superv:start_link().
//it opens fine
C^
erl
c(superv).
superv:start_link().
    ** exception exit: shutdown
//if i try again start_link() it is working
```

I got this. I deleted part responsible for starting mnesia and it worked fine, so I expect that instant quit (by ctrl+c) doesn't close mnesia properly. Unfortunately even if I invoke mnesia:stop(), before quicking and invoke start_link() again it returns exception exit. Please help me to resolve this matter.

Answer (score 1):

The not entirely right way to start mnesia is as an application.

```
application:start(mnesia).
```

before you start your application. It can be used when you are developing your system. For a real deployment, you want to generate a `release` with a *boot-script*. A release is a self-contained Erlang system you can start up on a foreign machine. You will write your own application, write a `my_application_name.app` file which contains a dependency on `mnesia`. Then you want to generate a release, typically with `reltool` and this release will then initialize by starting up mnesia before starting `my_application_name`. At least this is the *real* way to do it.

The tool like `rebar` can help you with maintaining your application and a `reltool.config` file for building your release.

Note that Mnesia needs a schema before it can start. A common trick is to have your release contain a default empty database which gets installed such that mnesias `dir` parameter points to it. Thus, if you start a newly generated system, it has a database to start from. And you can restart from scratch by re-installing the empty database. Check out `FALLBACK.BUP` in mnesia for hints on how to do this.

As for your errors, you can't start your server twice. The first time around, it registers itself under the atom `server` so a subsequent restart when it is already running will crash it. You can sometimes get a hint if you boot Erlang with the SASL application enabled. Either execute `application:start(sasl)` or run erlang like so:

```
erl -boot start_sasl
```

which substitutes the normal boot script with a variant that also starts SASL.

Comment: Thx for answer. I've added stop function: [http://pastebin.com/VziRrqEb ] (I've also supplied database init function). And now I can supervisor start_link(), then stop, and start it again and it works. But if close erlang shell. Open it again and invoke start_link() it, again, returns exception exit:shutdown (and obviously if i invoke (after error) it again it works). Can you help me to solve this out?

Comment: Yes, I can :) Your problem is that you are calling mnesia:create_schema(). This can only be done once and the next time you try to do that it fails somewhere in your init function. You should be asserting the answers from your mnesia:X calls so you know which one fails. `ok = mnesia:start()` for instance. The trick is to create a new empty database and then reinstall this one every time you want to start over. Look at the `FALLBACK.BUP` stuff i mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is right. I've written code like this:
    case mnesia:start() of
        ok -> ok;
        {error, Reason} -> io:format("Base start:~p\n", [Reason])%, {error ,Reason}
    end
But an error is not thrown. What is more i deleted create_schema/table from init and it still fails

Comment: And, can you tell me where i can read about it? Because mnesia:create_schema generates quasi binary symbols in FALLBACK.BUP. And also I've not found any info in documentation, and every example code I've found is doing it the same way I do